# Impossible to open the .qgs file I've just saved with QGIS 1.8

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm using QGIS 1.8.0 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 (last stable version of QGIS I downloaded yesterday).

After working yesterday and this morning on it, I'm trying to open it again, and QGIS asks me the username and password to access the PostGIS database and crashes after 10 seconds.

I also have QGIS 1.7 and 1.9 installed on my computer.

Here is the crash message, if this can help:

```
Process:         QGIS [342]
Path:            /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
Identifier:      org.qgis.qgis
Version:         1.8.0 (1.8.0 ())
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [124]

Date/Time:       2012-07-13 14:54:37.581 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          253852 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           18
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  15946 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   7
Anonymous UUID:                      4D1290E1-470F-4017-A8E7-1EA41258D661

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000610163
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libdelimitedtextprovider.so     0x000000011a2edeaf QgsDelimitedTextProvider::~QgsDelimitedTextProvider() + 35
1   libdelimitedtextprovider.so     0x000000011a2ede62 QgsDelimitedTextProvider::~QgsDelimitedTextProvider() + 18
2   org.qgis.qgis_core              0x0000000103e2d5b4 QgsProviderRegistry::provider(QString const&, QString const&) + 192
3   org.qgis.qgis_core              0x0000000103e50e2b QgsVectorLayer::setDataProvider(QString const&) + 89
4   org.qgis.qgis_core              0x0000000103e5b825 QgsVectorLayer::readXml(QDomNode const&) + 463
5   org.qgis.qgis_core              0x0000000103dfc763 QgsMapLayer::readXML(QDomNode const&) + 3999
6   org.qgis.qgis_core              0x0000000103e1e815 QgsProject::addLayer(QDomElement const&, QList<QDomNode>&, QList<QPair<QgsVectorLayer*, QDomElement> >&) + 1291
7   org.qgis.qgis_core              0x0000000103e1c910 QgsProject::_getMapLayers(QDomDocument const&) + 1378
8   org.qgis.qgis_core              0x0000000103e1f908 QgsProject::read() + 3760
9   org.qgis.qgis_core              0x0000000103e1ea23 QgsProject::read(QFileInfo const&) + 77
10  org.qgis.qgis                   0x00000001000240f4 QgisApp::addProject(QString) + 140
11  org.qgis.qgis                   0x0000000100026525 QgisApp::openProject(QString const&) + 55
12  org.qgis.qgis                   0x000000010001622e QgisApp::openFile(QString const&) + 108
13  org.qgis.qgis                   0x00000001000169ac QgisApp::event(QEvent*) + 40
14  QtGui                           0x0000000104d0193d QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 189
15  QtGui                           0x0000000104d07dc4 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 1060
16  org.qgis.qgis_core              0x0000000103da0762 QgsApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 100
17  QtCore                          0x0000000104a4a17c QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) + 124
18  org.qgis.qgis_core              0x0000000103da0ada QgsApplication::setFileOpenEventReceiver(QObject*) + 158
19  org.qgis.qgis                   0x000000010000bf52 QgisApp::QgisApp(QSplashScreen*, bool, QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>) + 5508
20  org.qgis.qgis                   0x0000000100008f52 main + 7938
21  org.qgis.qgis                   0x0000000100006c04 start + 52

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff895ffc0a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89601add _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff896017b4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff896012de _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89600c08 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff89600aa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000011a2f34a0  rbx: 0x000000011fbe61b0  rcx: 0x00007fff710b7650  rdx: 0x00000000005e8300
  rdi: 0x0000000000610163  rsi: 0x000000011fb00000  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfdee0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfdec0
   r8: 0x0000000000000001   r9: 0x000000011fbe67b0  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000015
  r12: 0x000000011fbe1fd8  r13: 0x000000011fbe1f10  r14: 0x000000011fbe5180  r15: 0x000000011fbe1f50
  rip: 0x000000011a2edeaf  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000610163
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to open the .qgs file with QGIS 1.7. It prompted a mistake but at least didn't crash.
The problem came from a CSV file that changed path (before I saved it).
Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Please report this bug if you haven't done so yet: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: Done: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6034

Comment: Your post has saved me days of work. I had the exact same problem. I tried opening a .qgs file that I have been working on for weeks using QGIS 1.8 and it crashed while loading. Thanks to your comment I checked the paths of the .csv files, realised I had changed one of them, changed it back and opened the .qgs file with QGIS 1.8 without glitch. THANK YOU!